Convergence and Fixed Points of a Recursive Sequence Involving Elementary Symmetric Functions
Definition 1:
Let $ a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_j $ be complex numbers. Define:
\begin{equation} 
a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{S_k(a_{n-j+1}, a_{n-j+2}, \ldots, a_n)},
\end{equation}
For $n+1 > j$.
Where $ S_k $ is the $ k $-th elementary symmetric function of the $ j $ variables $ a_{n-j+1}, a_{n-j+2}, \ldots, a_n $
The fixed points are given by
\begin{equation} 
a = \binom{j}{k}^{\frac{-1}{k+1}} e^{2\pi i \frac{l}{k+1}}, \quad \text{for } l = 0, 1, \ldots, k.
\end{equation}
IIRC, the convergence behaviour was somewhat interesting and not simple.
Definition 2:
Alternatively we can consider:
\begin{equation}
a_{n+1} = \frac{\binom{j}{k}}{s_k(a_{n-j+1}, a_{n-j+2}, \ldots, a_n)}  
\end{equation}
The fixed points are then roots of unity:
\begin{equation} 
a = e^{2\pi i \frac{l}{k+1}}, \quad \text{for } l = 0, 1, \ldots, k.
\end{equation}
These fixed points also seem to have a bit more of an interesting convergence / divergence behavior.
Questions

Which fixed points are stable and which ones are unstable?
Under what conditions does the sequence $ \{a_n\} $ converge?
How do particular values of $ j $ and $ k $ affect convergence to one of the above fixed points?

